# Hide ParentView and its children

Tags: android, android-view

There is a `View` item

```
View item = findViewById(R.id.item);
ViewParent = item.getParent();
```

I want to be able to hide item's parent with parent's children. How to do it ?

Comment: is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting ViewParent to View, something like this:

```
try {
    (View) ViewParent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // In case if item is the top most view
};
```

Catching exception is needed for situations when `item` is the top most view - then its parent is not a View.

Comment: Nope, there is no such method.

Comment: @boulder, according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent()): `Gets the parent of this view. Note that the parent is a ViewParent and not necessarily a View`, so not always it can be casted... am I right?

Comment: @Prizoff However there is no other way I think.

Comment: If it the rootmost view, then parent will be something like Window idk. If it is casual user view, parent will be ViewGroup. Just check android code how it works there.

Comment: Modified the answer aggregating all comments... not sure if try{} block is needed in real-world applications...

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the parent should also hide all its children AFAIK. So just :

```
parentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Nope, there is no such method.

Comment: using `ViewGroup` wouldn't fit your needs?